# Create Oanda Order Using httr::POST

Tags: r, post, httr, oanda

I am trying to create a market order on Oanda using httr::POST and am receiving a status code 415 error and the order is not being created. No expert here so please help me see what I am doing wrong.

Documentation from Oanda on API requests can be found here: https://developer.oanda.com/rest-live-v20/order-ep/#collapse_endpoint_2

Comment: OP don't put your answer in the question! But good on you for solving your problem yourself! :-)

Answer (score 0):

> After a health amount of googling and trial here is what works in case
> anyone else needs it. Note the content_type_json() inside POST:
>
> ```
> URL_Orders<-'https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{AccountID}/orders'
> #replace {AccountID} with the account ID for the account (no {}) Token<-{Token} #fill with API Token generated from Oanda (no {})
>
> #create the body for the request req = list(   order = list(instrument="EUR_USD",
>                units="1000", 
>                type="MARKET",
>                timeInForce="FOK",
>                positionFill="DEFAULT"
>                ) )
>
> #format body as JSON body<-toJSON(req, auto_unbox = T, pretty = FALSE)
>
> #post request Test<-httr::POST(URL_Orders, 
>                  content_type_json(),
>                  add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer ", Token)), 
>                  body=body,
>                  encode = "form",
>                  verbose(data_out = TRUE, data_in = TRUE, info = TRUE))
> ```

- OP